# moq System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper Partial method

Tags: moq

does anyone knows how to mock HtmlHelper.Partial?

I've created my own htmlhelper class and one of the feature of the said helper class is to return an MvcHtmlString of `htmlHelper.Partial`.

Example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString ScriptEditorFor(this HtmlHelper<ViewModel> htmlHelper,
    Identifiers.PainAssessmentVariables painVariable)
{
     return htmlHelper.Partial("test");
}
```

I'm getting null reference exception when I try to moq test this

Comment: What class are you going to test? Why do you need to mock `HtmlHelper.Partial`? How does your test look like?

Comment: I've created an extension method for HtmlHelper. 
example:
public static MvcHtmlString ScriptEditorFor(this HtmlHelper<LeadInformationViewModel> htmlHelper)
{ 
 return htmlHelper.Partial("Test") 
}

Now I need to unit test the said method using moq.

example:

public void AllParties()
{
 var htmlHelper = new HtmlHelper<LeadInformationViewModel>(viewContext, viewDataContainer.Object, routes);
 var test = htmlHelper.ScriptEditorFor(Identifiers.PainAssessmentVariables.AllParties, currentRoute);
 Assert.AreEqual(source, test.ToHtmlString());
}

Comment: Pls, edit your question and include all the data from your comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `Partial` is a static method (an extension method), and moq can't mock static methods.

You have to eihter hide the call to `Partial` behind an interface, or use a mocking framework that is capable of mocking static methods.